# How do I list my pip-installed packages inside a venv?

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I have successfully activated a virtual environment and installed packages there, but when I try to list those packages with `pip list` I get the list of global packages, not those in the activated venv.

```
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
[venv] pip list
# ... global 2.7 packages are listed
[venv] pip3 list
# ... global 3 packages are listed
```

but

```
$ cd venv/lib/pythonXX/site-packages
$ ls
# ...venv's installed packages are listed
```

even though `python -version` correctly lists the venv's Python (and not any global version).

How do I list my pip-installed packages inside a venv?

Comment: `pip freeze` should do this, if I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: `pip list --local`

Comment: check out `which pip` or `pyenv which pip` (if using pyenv). I though that list of packages is `pip freeze` command :/

Comment: @Aiven: That shows the global pip (for the wrong version of Python).

Comment: maybe `pip3` is bonded to venv

Comment: If your virtualenv is properly configured, `which pip` should be inside the virtualenv, and `pip list` should only show packages in that virtualenv. I suspect you're running the system `pip`. Try doing `rehash` to refresh the cached `$PATH`.

Comment: Inside your sourced venv, you should have a local `pip` executable: `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip list`. If this fails or shows the system site packages, either your venv was created with a python executable that is not found on your machine (like for example when you copied the venv dir from another machine), or your `PATH` inside the venv is mangled, or the venv is broken beyond repair.

Comment: Also (at least on *nixes), virtual envs are not relocatable, so once you move them, consider them broken - this is because all the shebangs contain hardcoded paths that are set on venv creation.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this problem by creating a new venv for my project and switch to it. Then, when I activate the venv and "pip list" into it, I list only venv packages. I think this problem happens when you rename project folder or venv folder or move those files maybe to reorganise your project structure.